# Use the value of node author's field as CSS class

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I have a user profile field which gets populated by the Rules module. I want to add that value to the body class of nodes that user creates.

Which hook should I use to achieve this? What code do I exactly need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are added to the body element in [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), so in your `MYMODULE_preprocess_html()` or `MYTHEME_preprocess_html()` you would need code similar to the following one.

```php
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object() && $node->uid && $account = user_load($node->uid)) {
    $user_field = field_get_items('user', $account, $field_name);
        
   // Use $user_field[0] to access the field data.
 }
}
```

Replace `$field_name` with the field machine name, including the field_ part if present in the field name. Note I used a variable as placeholder, but you should use a literal string.

Notice that the structure of `$user_field` depends from the field being used; you need to know it to write the correct code.